# How to verify login and render conditionally (ReactJS and Firebase)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-lifecycle

I want to make sure that a user is logged in before running rendering either A or B.

When I console.log it, I get a true in return when I check if I'm logged in, however wrong if-statement gets rendered.

I think that it's because firebase takes its time to load and my function renders before firebase has done this.

```
const renderForm = () => {

  let isLoggedin = false;
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      isLoggedin = true;
      console.log(isLoggedin + " Logged in")
    } else {
      isLoggedin = false;
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedin ? (<AddNewCountryForm />) : (<p>You have to log in</p>)}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Can someone explain how I should go ahead and solve this? Obviously, I want to render the component if user is logged in.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `isLoggedIn` to React state and not local variable.

As per below code, when `isLoggedIn` is `false`, you should see `<p>You have to log in</p>` else `AddNewCountryForm` component should render.

```
   const renderForm = () => {

      const [isLoggedin, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        setIsLoggedIn(!!user);
      });
      return (
        <div>
          {isLoggedin ? (<AddNewCountryForm />) : (<p>You have to log in</p>)}

        </div>
      )
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure did. Thanks alot. As you may understand, I'm very new to react and I'm still trying to get used to states. Learning is hard. Thanks once again, Sandy. :)